# Is it possible to use 2 laptop screens as a one in windows 8 on ultra book of dell

Tags: windows-8, display, hdmi, ultrabook, extended-desktop

I want to use only one laptop and only the screen of the other laptop to extend the desktop. Is it possible to merge or extend screen?

I am a professional sound producer so its convenient to have more space by extending screen for me. Is this possible?

My ultra book does not have VGA port it only has an HDMI port.

Answer (score 0):

[Air Display](http://www.avatron.com/apps/air-display/) has you covered.
Or from microsoft
[Mouse without borders](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35460)